# jquery GET and POST confusion

Tags: php, ajax

I am not quiet sure how jquery works. I want to know few things about the GET and POST in terms of jQuery.

I use the following code in my app :

```
<script>
function example_ajax_request() {
  $('#example-placeholder').html('<p>Loading results ... <img src="ajax-loader.gif"  /></p>');
  $('#example-placeholder').load("ind.php?show=" + $('#box option:selected').val());
}
</script>
```

I am not using either GET or POST in this method. 
I am using a button to call the `example_ajax_request` to process the request and get the results.

Sometimes I see code like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'loader.php',
  data: 'somedata',
  method: 'GET',
  success: function(data){
    $('#er').text(data);
  }
});
```

My doubt is, is it required or not that we use a method to post the data? (either GET or POST) while send and getting the data in PHP webapps? 
The code that I use first works fine even though I do not use any POST or GET methods.

Any inputs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

"Read the manual" - http://api.jquery.com/load/

> The POST method is used if data is
>   provided as an object; otherwise, GET
>   is assumed.

Answer (score 2):

Using `.load()` in the way you did, it requests the resource via `GET`. By appending parameters to the URL (`?param1=value1`) you are providing "`GET` parameters".

This:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'loader.php',
  data: 'param1=value1',
  method: 'GET',
  success: function(data){
    $('#er').text(data);
  }
});
```

is basically the same as

```
$('#er').load('loader.php?param1=value');
```

The advantage of the first method is, among others, that you can do a lot more inside the callback function (`success :function(){}`) than just putting the content into an element. You gain more control. Read about [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

---

The differences between `GET` and `POST` is that using the `GET` method, parameters are sent as part of the URL whereas with `POST`, parameters are sent in the body of the request. Thus it is easier to provide parameters via `GET`. On the other hand, URLs cannot be of arbitrary length so sending parameters via `GET` is limited.

`GET` should be used if you really only want to **get** data. Parameters can be used to control the output (e.g. this is used when you paginate are result set).

`POST` on the other hand should be used if you want to **change** data on the server side.

Read more about the [request methods on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods).

Comment: this is correct GET is implicit in .load() and you are using it without knowing it.

Answer (score 2):

All data you send to a server from a browser (in the normal case) will be via [HTTP verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http#Request_methods) (request methods), almost always `GET` or `POST` although there are others. `GET` is what browsers send to servers when you want to visit a web page, for instance. `POST` is almost always what's used to send forms to servers, for various reasons.

jQuery ajax methods can use `GET` or `POST` depending on what you tell them to do. [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) actually decides for you based on the data you tell it to send with the request. jQuery's [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), and [`jQuery.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) functions let you say specifically what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to read the manual.
http://api.jquery.com/load/

> "The POST method is used if data is
>   provided as an object; otherwise, GET
>   is assumed."

Answer (score 0):

Both .load() and .ajax() do GET request by default. The result is often the same, but in order to be a good developer you have to understand the differences and the philosophy for each of them. Get seems to be easier to use at is more transparent in terms of passed information. You pass visible parameters. POST allows bigger and more complex information to be passed.

In terms of vocabulary, the purists say that GET should GET information and POST should POST it.

Advice: GET requests are cacheable by browser so add extra param with timestamp to make the content refresh.

As a reccomandation I would use ajax() with POST as ajax is a complex request that allows you to handle all errrors.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html